# Does this jquery support timepicker

Tags: jquery

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-css'  href='admin.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link rel='stylesheet' id='colors-fresh-css'  href='colors-fresh.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

Does script `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"` support timepick?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js
```

This has a `datepicker`.

**Full documentation & Examples**:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

**Tutorials**:

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-UI-Datepicker-Widget-P1015.html
http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/jquery-ui-datepicker-tutorial/